# Order of units and their square roots, modulo a prime congruent to 1 mod 8

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose I have a prime, $p\equiv 1 \bmod{8}$, with $\sigma_{p}\equiv \frac{p-1}{8}\equiv 3\bmod{4}$.  How will $\text{ord }_{p}\left(3\right)$ compare to $\text{ord }_{p}\left(\sqrt{3}\right)$?

I would like to know if there will always be some $k\in\mathbb{Z^{*}}$ such that $$\left(1+i\sqrt{2}\right)^{2^{k}\sigma_{p}}\equiv -1\bmod{p} \text{ or } \left(1-i\sqrt{2}\right)^{2^{k}\sigma_{p}}\equiv -1\bmod{p}.$$

$$\text{Note: }\left(1+i\sqrt{2}\right)\left(1-i\sqrt{2}\right) = 3$$

Furthermore, if $3\mid \sigma_{p}$, i.e., $3$ is a square mod $p$, how does this affect things?

Answer (score 1):

In general, in a group, if $g=h^2$, then
$$
o(g)=\frac{o(h)}{\gcd(2,o(h))}
$$

In words, $o(g)=o(h)$ if $o(h)$ is odd and $o(g)=o(h)/2$ if $o(h)$ is even.